# How to create png from array of pixel color data in PHP?

Tags: php, image

Lets say I have an arrays of pixels. Basically an array of this data {x,y,r,g,b,a} for each pixel.

How would I go about converting all this data into an actual image file (png preferably)?

Could not find a solution. Any help would be very appreciated.

Comment: You would need to decide on a format and read up the specification on how it stores the data. It would be more productive to find a library that does this of course. As it stands, this question is not well suited for the Q&A format of this site because it is open-ended and vague.

Comment: @patatahooligan I think that would be the case if PHP's standard library didn't include this functionality. But it does, so I think it fits the format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had some time to code up a little example. You should be able to see and note that:

- the red component increases towards the bottom of the image
- the green component increases towards the right of the image
- the blue component is absent
- the alpha channel is random and between 0 (opaque) and 127 (fully transparent)

---

```
// Define width and height
$w=800;
$h=600;

// Create truecolour image so we can have infinitely many colours rather than a limited palette
$img=imagecreatetruecolor($w,$h);
imagesavealpha($img,true);
imagealphablending($img,false);

// Iterate over all pixels
for($y=0;$y<$h;$y++){
   for($x=0;$x<$w;$x++){
      $r     = round(255*$y/$h);
      $g     = round(255*$x/$w);
      $b     = 0;
      $alpha = rand(0,127);
      $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($img,$r,$g,$b,$alpha);
      imagesetpixel($img,$x,$y,$color);
   }
}

// Save result
imagepng($img,"result.png");
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I'll admit I haven't actually used this API, but looks like PHP has what you're looking for.

You create an image identifier with [imagecreate](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreate.php) or one of the related functions, then color in each pixel with [imagesetpixel](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagesetpixel.php), using a color identifier created with [imagecolorallocatealpha](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolorallocatealpha.php). From there you should be able to output as a PNG with [imagepng](http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagepng.php).

It's worth noting that this image library seems to support drawing lines and shapes and other structures higher than the per-pixel level, so I'd also look into whether your code necessarily needs to build a big pixel array, rather than drawing the image some other way.

Comment: Thank you, will do some testing in a bit.

Comment: Nice! You'll give yourself the best chance of success with least effort using `imagecreatetruecolor()`.